# Can I read the Google Analytics API Time On Site in Minutes instead of Seconds?

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm very new to APIs, Java and all this things.

I Googled and over-googled things about the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) and found very few answers. So I thought I'd post my question here.

The [ga:avgSessionDuration](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_avgsessionduration) returns the average sessions duration on my sites. But it returns in **seconds** and **miliseconds**. I want that number divided by 60 so I'll se minutes (as I see it on the Google Analytics website). But I have no clue how to do that and found no answer on Google.

Here is my code:

```
  'dimensions': 'ga:yearMonth',
  'metrics': 'ga:users,ga:pageviews,ga:avgSessionDuration',
  'start-date': '2014-01-02',
  'end-date': 'today',
  'max-results': '12',
    'sort': '-ga:yearMonth',
```

The return info is:

```
Month of Year   Users   Pageviews   Avg. Session Duration
201505           18       25         27.894736842105264
201504           475      685        38.3062381852552
```

Another thing I hate is that the Months are printed out as "201505" instead of "May 2015".

Cheers. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the documentation:

> [ga:avgSessionDuration](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_avgsessionduration) 
>   Web View Name: Avg. Session Duration The
>   average duration of user sessions represented in total **seconds**.
>   ga:sessionDuration / ga:sessions

The [Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) returns the data to you in seconds.  This is to make it easer for all developers to then format the information as they wish.  You as a developer will need to loop though the results add your divide by 60 in order to format your data in minutes.

Google returns raw data formatting is up to us.

The same goes for Month of Year the standard format is YYYYMM you will need to format the data in your code.